# How toChange ManyToManyField Size?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

Can anyone help me in this problem.
I have a ManyToManyField in django admin, I want to resize the field and make it bigger.

Can Anyone help me please.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In your `Admin` class containing the ManyToMany-Field, add the following:

```
filter_horizontal = ('m2m_field',)
```

or

```
filter_vertical = ('m2m_field',)
```

where `m2m_field` is your ManyToMany-Field defined in your Models.

That's the easiest method to make the ManyToMany-Field look bigger and more user-friendly.